# Pandas: How to select columns with non-zero value in a sparse table

Tags: python, pandas

I have a sparse table with 2000 column and I want to select few specific rows and their non-zero values. how can I do it?

```
    id       name   e1   e2   e3   e4 . . e550 . . e1200 .   e1760. . e2000
    1      engine1   0   0    0    2322   1300               140       0
    2      engine2   0   0  1230   0        0        2100              0
    .
    .
    .
    998000


df[df.name==engine2 & ? ]
    id    name      e3       e1200
    2   engine2    1230       2100
```

and

```
df[df.name==engine1 & ? ]

    id    name      e4       e550     e1760
    1   engine1    2322       1300      140
```

Comment: If `engine1` is `engine2` what is desired output?

Answer (score 5):

You can filter twice - first rows by mask `m1` and then column by `m2`.
Last use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
m1 = (df['name'] == 'engine2')
m2 = (df[m1] != 0).all()

print (df.loc[m1,m2])
   id     name    e3  e1200
1   2  engine2  1230   2100
```

Answer (score 1):

So basically to filter out please use

`new_df = df.loc[<enter row number here>]`
`new_df = new_df[new_df != 0]`

This new_df will now have the required non-zero values