# select column with non-zero values from dataframe

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have data like the data below.  I would like to only return the columns from the dataframe that contain at least one non-zero value.  So in the example below it would be column ALF.  Returning non-zero rows doesn’t seem that tricky but selecting the column and records is giving me a little trouble.

```
print df

Data:

Type             ADR             ALE     ALF               AME  
Seg0              0.0            0.0     0.0              0.0   
Seg1              0.0            0.0     0.5              0.0
```

When I try something like the link below:

[Pandas: How to select columns with non-zero value in a sparse table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44453059/pandas-how-to-select-columns-with-non-zero-value-in-a-sparse-table)

```
m1 = (df['Type'] == 'Seg0')
m2 = (df[m1] != 0).all()

print (df.loc[m1,m2])
```

I get a key error for 'Type'

Answer (score 8):

In my opinion you get `key error` because first column is `index`:

Solution use [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) for check at least one non zero value to mask and then filter index of `True`s:

```
m2 = (df != 0).any()
a = m2.index[m2]
print (a)
Index(['ALF'], dtype='object')
```

Or if need `list`:

```
a = m2.index[m2].tolist()
print (a)
['ALF']
```

Similar solution is filter columns names:

```
a = df.columns[m2]
```

**Detail**:

```
print (m2)
ADR    False
ALE    False
ALF     True
AME    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Well explained and succinct : -)